# Which class library type do I use with a Core 1.0 RC2 (.NET Framework) Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-1.0

In ASP.NET Core RC2 Microsoft split the Core web application into two separate templates:

ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)
and
ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Core)

I am planning on developing an app that is net 451 only. If I go the (.NET Framework) path. What type of class libraries should I be using? I assumed Class Library (.NET Core), but when I tried adding reference from a project with the (.NET Framework Template) it says it can't add reference to .NET Standard.

Maybe I shouldn't be using the .NET Framework template. The main reason why I feel like I should be is because I do not want to have to deal with developing for the other operating systems and not having access to certain packages like email and transactionscope, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set your class library to target net451 also it will work.

Change project.json in class library project as follows...

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, .NET Standard can reference .NET Core libraries, but .NET Core cannot reference .NET Standard libraries.

So, it comes down to the end-use of your application.  If it's only going to run (or be hosted) on Windows, then use the larger, more established .NET Standard for the application (although you can choose to put common code in .NET Core projects in the same solution for future cross-platform re-use).  However, if there's a requirement to run/host it on another platform (Linux, Mac), then you'll have to use the younger .NET Core.